# Swiss: Does SBB EasyRide take into account a Z-Pass

Tags: trains, public-transport, switzerland, zurich, mobile-apps

This question is about the Switzerland SBB app and the Zürich partner network annual pass (Z-Pass).

I use the "swipe on" EasyRide feature in the SBB app for most public transportation travel in Switzerland.

I'm considering getting a Z-Pass for my regular commute to work.

My question is this: Will EasyRide know about the specific Z-Pass I will purchase?  My pass will be for the specific zones that my home-work commute crosses. Will EasyRide only charge me for zones that aren't included in the Z-Pass?

For a normal commute, I probably wouldn't swipe on. But If I take a train to Winterthur, I'd want to swipe on at the start and not worry about which zones I'm passing through.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to mlc's research to find [Does EasyRide take my travelcards into account?](https://www.sbb.ch/en/help-and-contact/produkte-services/apps/sbb-mobile-sbb-preview/faq-easyride.html), the answer is **Yes**, with some exceptions. Specifically:

> Yes. EasyRide takes your saved Half Fare and regional Travelcards into account and applies them to any relevant journey in your travelcard area. Travelcards can be edited in the “EasyRide” tile in the menu. In the event of a ticket inspection, both the EasyRide ticket and the saved travelcard must be shown to the ticket inspection staff.
> The following travelcards are NOT taken into account by EasyRide. Please purchase your zone upgrade separately in the app or at a point of sale:
>
> <full list omitted, as it may get outdated>

Answer (score 2):

For greater certainty, you can always check which travelcards are listed in your account in the app (or on the website https://swisspass.ch).

Almost all commuter travelcards are nowadays issued in electronic form and associated with the traveller's SwissPass.

Sometimes there may be a synchronization issue and you may have to re-login or wait a couple of days.

The EasyRide tab will indicate which travelcards are taken into account and display a warning for the travelcard not taken into account. You may also manually add regional travelcards (issued on paper or otherwise on an anonymous basis) in the application (when modifying traveller details).

For example:

[image]